# Installing the R interpeter and R as a shared library uder the same tree

Tags: r, installation, shared-libraries, rpy2

I am a bit confused about how to install R (via compilation) as a shared library.

The instructions [here](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy_faq.html) ([Rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2.html)) say that I should do the following:

```
  # <go to the R source directory>
  make distclean
  ./configure --enable-R-shlib
  make
  make install
```

but the first `make` (`make distclean`) would remove any previous installation of R under the same directory tree (e.g. the contents of the `bin` folder).

What if I want to use the same installation for the R interpreter and the shared libraries? For example, say I want to use the interpreter to install R packages, and then the shared library of the installation to call R (and those packages) from Rpy2.

Otherwise, how can I install R packages for use through Rpy2?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
./configure --enable-R-shlib
```

Will tell to build R's shared libraries in addition to what is normally built (the executable, the documentation, etc...)

Also

```
make install
```

will install R (default is `/usr/local`). This is where you'll want to find your R executable. Calling `make distclean` will only affect the build directory, not the installed R.

Comment: +1 -- and what Laurent describes has been the default on Debian (and hence derivatives such as Ubuntu) for over a decade. And for what it is worth, I do look after the R as well as RPy and RPy2 packages which you could just install pre-built.

Comment: Thanks! With this, if I install packages using the interpreter, will the packages be available later from the Python-RPy2 interface?

Comment: Yes. If custom settings for R_LIBS or the install path, you'll have to pay attention to it.