# Rpy2 windows installation through Git Bash

Tags: r, windows, git-bash, rpy2

I first encountered the error referenced here:

[Installing rpy2 on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49915714/installing-rpy2-on-windows)

which is that I couldn't install rpy2 because '.sh' isn't recognized by the default windows terminal as a command. To get around that, I'm using a Git Bash terminal, but then I get the error mentioned here:

[Installing the R interpeter and R as a shared library uder the same tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224871/installing-the-r-interpeter-and-r-as-a-shared-library-uder-the-same-tree?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

However, the solution in that post is for a Linux install only (I think).

As I understood that post, I should navigate to the bin/ directory in R and run ./configure (which doesn't exist in my directory).   Any thoughts on how to fix this error for a Windows install?

Comment: Perhaps you could try with cygwin?

Comment: You need to build using the same set of tools used to build R on Windows. See the Windows appendix in the Installation and Administration manual. You may also need a POSIX shell like msys2.